# $T$ is an operator on inner product space, how to prove $T$ is invertible iff $T^*$ is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $T$ is an operator on inner product space, how do we prove that $T$ is invertible iff $T^*$ is invertible?

Can I change the goal to prove $T$ is injective iff $T^*$ is injective?

Comment: Look this up-http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410532/invertibility-in-a-finite-dimensional-inner-product-space

Comment: You should probably be assuming that the underlying space is complete. Otherwise, there's a nice example given of a bounded operator that doesn't have an adjoint: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29140/adjoint-of-a-linear-transformation-in-an-infinite-dimension-inner-product-space